# Proving a sequence converges and finding its limit

Tags: real-analysis

Let C>0 and let a sequence $(x_i)$ be defined as $x_1=\sqrt{C}$, and let $x_{i+1}=\sqrt{C+x_i}$, prove that it is convergent and find it's limit.

Ok so I have found that the sequence is strictly increasing through induction, but I am having problems showing that it is bounded from above, where then I'd use monotone convergence theorem.  I tried using induction but I run into issues no matter what I think of for my bound because it differs if C<1 and if C>1.  Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the upper bound as $1+2\sqrt{C}$ then use induction.

Then by monotone convergence theorem, the limit exist. Then you get a quadratic equation. After solving it and reject the negative root, you can find the limit.

Comment: Thanks that's a great trick to add the one, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

$x_1 \leq 1+2\sqrt{C}$, and
$x_i \leq 1+2\sqrt{C} \to x_{i+1}\leq \sqrt{C+2\sqrt{C}+1}=\sqrt{C}+1\leq 1+2\sqrt{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x_n=\underbrace{\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+...+\sqrt{c}}}}_\text{n-times}$$
by induction one can show that for all $n$
$$x_n<1+2\sqrt{c}$$
for $n=1$
$$x_1=\sqrt{c}<1+2\sqrt{c}$$
assume it is true for $n=k$ then let $n=k+1$. We get (since $c>0$):
$$x_{k+1}=\sqrt{c+x_{k}}<\sqrt{c+1+2\sqrt{c}}=\sqrt{(1+\sqrt{c})^2}=1+\sqrt{c}<1+2\sqrt{c}<\infty$$
Now let $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=L$ then
$$L=\sqrt{c+L}\Rightarrow L^2-L-c=0\Rightarrow L=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4c}}{2}$$
We ignored the other root as $x_n>0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{C+x}$, and note that $f$ is increasing on $[-C,\infty)$.

Let $\phi(x) = f(x)-x$, note that $\phi(0) >0$, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} \phi(x) = -\infty$.

Let $x^* $ be the smallest $x$ such that $\phi(x) = 0$. We have $x^* = f(x^*)$, squaring gives $(x^*)^2-(x^*)-C = 0$, from which we get $x^*= {1 \over 2} (1 + \sqrt{1+4C})$.

Then if $0 \le x < x^*$, $\phi(x)>0$ and $f(x) < f(x^*)$, so $x < f(x) < f(x^*)=x^*$.

Hence if $x_0 < x^*$, then induction shows that $x_n < x_{n+1} < x^*$. Consequently, $x_n$ has a limit $\hat{x}$, and since
$x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$, we see that $\hat{x} = f(\hat{x})$, and since $x_n < x^*$, we see that $\hat{x} \le x^*$ and so $ \hat{x} = x^*$ (since it is the smallest such $x$).